# Image inaccessible from python script but accessible in browser

Tags: python-3.x, urllib, http-status-code-403

I was trying to automatically download some traffic camera photos to play around with some image object recognition scripts and I have found that some links to them will throw a `403: Forbidden` error when I try to download them from Python, and yet I can access them in a browser. One such image is at this link: https://www.svz-bw.de/kamera/ftpdata/KA101/KA101_gross.jpg

This code:

`urllib.request.urlretrieve("https://www.svz-bw.de/kamera/ftpdata/KA101/KA101_gross.jpg", "traffic.jpg")`

Returns a 403 error for me. What gives? I can understand that perhaps these organizations are not keen on having people bog down their servers with automatic downloads and perhaps there are some GDPR-related constraints, but I am actually more curious about how they are able to detect that the request is coming from a script and not from normal use

Comment: quite a few websites check the user-agent http header and block exotic ones. You can check if it's the case here by setting this header to a well known value (there are lists of common browsers UA on the web).